# How can I filter a FolderBrowserDialog, or what's an alternative?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to restrict folders in a FolderBrowserDialog that appear by default.  For instance, "Homegroup", "Recycle Bin", "Control Panel" etc.  Is there any way to work with the existing FolderBrowserDialog, or do I need to look at an alternative control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant do it from the application but you have to create your own user control.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer to your question, but if you set the `FolderBrowserDialog.RootFolder` 
you get
`Only the specified folder and any subfolders that are beneath it will appear in the dialog box and be selectable.` (From MSDN)